# SWIFT work with arrays and dictionaries

Tags: arrays, json, swift, dictionary

I'm trying to pass information to the second controller through the segue from the array:

```
var gists = [Gists]()
```

this is how my implementation of the method **prepare(for segue:** looks like

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "detailSegue" {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                 guard let dvc = segue.destination as? DetailViewController else { return }
                dvc.filename = gists[indexPath.row].files.key // type String
                dvc.rawUrl = gists[indexPath.row].files.value // type String
            }
        }
    }
```

this is the dump of my array **gists**:

```
▿ 2 elements
  ▿ GistShowApp.Gists
    ▿ description: Optional("mySecondGist")
      - some: "mySecondGist"
    ▿ files: 1 key/value pair
      ▿ (2 elements)
        - key: "gistfile1.txt"
        ▿ value: GistShowApp.DetailGist
          ▿ filename: Optional("gistfile1.txt")
            - some: "gistfile1.txt"
          ▿ rawUrl: Optional("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/VladimirKhuraskin/9ca2362c09cebcc16bd74f51f267231a/raw/74caacd3ad3eedb369a07b926327d2ef37e3eefc/gistfile1.txt")
            - some: "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/VladimirKhuraskin/9ca2362c09cebcc16bd74f51f267231a/raw/74caacd3ad3eedb369a07b926327d2ef37e3eefc/gistfile1.txt"
  ▿ GistShowApp.Gists
    ▿ description: Optional("helloWorldDemo")
      - some: "helloWorldDemo"
    ▿ files: 1 key/value pair
      ▿ (2 elements)
        - key: "gistfile1.txt"
        ▿ value: GistShowApp.DetailGist
          ▿ filename: Optional("gistfile1.txt")
            - some: "gistfile1.txt"
          ▿ rawUrl: Optional("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/VladimirKhuraskin/c510014b85a6bdfa302f1f3837893a7c/raw/4648e701849ee7d52fb685111a7f0e4323505a35/gistfile1.txt")
            - some: "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/VladimirKhuraskin/c510014b85a6bdfa302f1f3837893a7c/raw/4648e701849ee7d52fb685111a7f0e4323505a35/gistfile1.txt"
2018-06-30 15:30:26.336720+0400 GistShowApp[1889:720551] [Snapshotting] Snapshotting a view (0x134032c00, UIKeyboardImpl) that is not in a visible window requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.
```

That is, I have an array of elements **gists**, each of which consists of a string and a dictionary. In turn, this dictionary is of type **[String: String]**. And I need to pass the key and the corresponding value.

Xcode produces an error on these lines. How to write them correctly?

```
dvc.filename = gists[indexPath.row].files.key
dvc.rawUrl = gists[indexPath.row].files.value
```

Answer (score 0):

`gists[indexPath.row].files` is a dictionary, so you will need to set `dvc.filename` and `dvc.rawUrl` to one entry in that dictionary, or pass the whole dictionary to the detail view controller.

For the first option:

```
dvc.filename = gists[indexPath.row].files["gistfile1.txt"].filename
dvc.rawUrl = gists[indexPath.row].files["gistfile1.txt"].rawURL
```